# Excel: How can I add custom gridline to a chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, gridlines

How can I add a custom horizontal line that has a label and it is at the exact same level as the first column in the chart (see the screenshot below).

Can this be done in VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in VBA, or it could be done without VBA:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzSeries.html

This method involves creating a secondary Y-axis, and plotting another series of data in a "line" on the second axis.

This is a fairly clean solution.

Otherwise with VBA you would need add a shape/line to the chart (important to add it to the chartObject and not to the Worksheet).

Then compute the height of points and make the line's `.Left` = the chart's `.PlotArea.Left` and make the line's `.Width` = to the chart's `.PlotArea.Width`.  Then set the line's `.Top` value  based on the chart's `.PlotArea.Height` minus the "height" you calculated for the point.

Answer (score 2):

using vba, you can add a new series:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Values = "={6.9,6.9,6.9,6.9}" 
    'create string beforehand if number and values are unknown
    .ChartType = xlLine
    'and whatever other formatting is needed
End With
```

not using VBA, you can add a new column to the data, and put all of it equal to the first item, using `=$B$2` in each cell to add the line to the graph